# Reset a sum in a query when a date field changes month

Tags: sql-server

I am currently executing the following query:

```
Select *, Balance = SUM(DailyReAdmits) 
OVER (ORDER BY Date_Total ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
From #AllReadmits
```

Which returns these results:

```
Date_Total    DailyReAdmits    Balance
2015-08-25                4          4
2015-08-26                8         12
2015-08-27                9         21
2015-08-28                3         24
2015-08-29                1         25
2015-08-30                4         29
2015-08-31                3         32
2015-09-01                5         37
```

However, when a new month starts, I would like the balance to start over again and look like this:

```
Date_Total    DailyReAdmits    Balance
2015-08-25                4          4
2015-08-26                8         12
2015-08-27                9         21
2015-08-28                3         24
2015-08-29                1         25
2015-08-30                4         29
2015-08-31                3         32
2015-09-01                5          5
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: tag sql-server (2012-2014) and check my answer ;).

Answer (score 1):

I supposed that you want partition by month, so try this:

```
SELECT *, Balance = SUM(DailyReAdmits) 
OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(MM,Date_Total) ORDER BY Date_Total ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM #AllReadmits
```